# How to detect if a rails app is running under Unicorn?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unicorn

I need to setup a connection to an external service in my Rails app.  I do this in an initializer.  The problem is that the service library uses threaded delivery (which I need, because I can't have it bogging down requests), but the Unicorn life cycle causes the thread to be killed and the workers never see it.  One solution is to invoke a new connection on every request, but that is unnecessarily wasteful.

The optimal solution is to setup the up the connection in an after_fork block in the unicorn config.  The problem there is that doesn't get invoked outside of unicorn, which means we can't test it in development/testing environments.

So the question is, what is the best way to determine whether a Rails app is running under Unicorn (either master or worker process)?

Answer (score 3):

There is an environment variable that is accessible in Rails (I know it exists in 3.0 and 3.1), check the value of `env['SERVER_SOFTWARE']`. You could just put a regex or string compare against that value to determine what server you are running under.

I have a template in my admin that goes through the env variable and spits out its content.

**Unicorn 4.0.1**

```
env['SERVER_SOFTWARE'] => "Unicorn 4.0.1"
```

**rails server (webrick)**

```
env['SERVER_SOFTWARE'] => "WEBrick/1.3.1 (Ruby/1.9.3/2011-10-30)"
```

Answer (score 3):

You can check for `defined?(Unicorn)` and in your Gemfile set: `gem :unicorn, require: false`
In fact you don't need Unicorn library loaded in you rails application.
Server is started by `unicorn` command from shell

Answer (score 1):

Checking for `Unicorn` constant seems a good solution, **BUT** it depends very much on whether `require: false` is provided in the `Gemfile`. If it isn't (which is quite probable), the check might give a false positive.

I've solved it in a very straightforward manner:

```
# `config/unicorn.rb` (or alike):
ENV["UNICORN"] = 1

...

# `config/environments/development.rb` (or alike):
...
# Log to stdout if Web server is Unicorn.
if ENV["UNICORN"].to_i > 0
  config.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)
end
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You could check to see if the Unicorn module has been defined with `Object.constants.include?('Unicorn')`.

This is very specific to Unicorn, of course.  A more general approach would be to have a method which sets up your connection and remembers it's already done so.  If it gets called multiple times, it just returns doing nothing on subsequent calls.  Then you call the method in after_fork and in a before_filter in your application controller.  If it's been run in the after_fork it does nothing in the before_filter, if it hasn't been run yet it does its thing on the first request and nothing on subsequent requests.

Answer (score 0):

Inside `config/unicorn.rb`
Define ENV variable as

`ENV['RAILS_STDOUT_LOG']='1'
worker_processes 3
timeout 90`

and then this variable `ENV['RAILS_STDOUT_LOG']` will be accessible anywhere in your Rails app worker thread.

**my issue:**
I wanted to output all the logs(SQL queries) when on the Unicorn workers and not on any other workers on Heroku, so what I did is adding env variable in the unicorn configuration file

Answer (score 0):

If you use `unicorn_rails`, below code will help

```
defined?(::Unicorn::Launcher)
```